# how to remove dialshock 2 ribbon flex board?

Tags: pcb, connector, ribbon-cable, flexible

my dualshock 2 has a connector to the ribbon board and looks like this
[connector](https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/3VnPgfBTX3QRs4QO.huge)

can someone tell me the proper way to remove the flex board from this connector while leaving the connector in working order?

Answer (score 1):

Just pull it out carefully. There's no latch.

Comment: with what do i pull it out? do i use a small screwdriver and to pry it in-between?

Comment: i cant pull it out, i tried with maximum force and even damaged my skin a bit and it didn't move at all.